# Replace values falling inside a triangle in Matlab

Tags: matlab, grid

I have a 2D array of n x n dimension with value 1 in each of the grid locations (as shown in the Figure). I want to change values (from 1 to 0) for those grid points falling inside a triangle defined by edge coordinates (p1,p2,p3) in Matlab.

[image: Left side figure shows the current 2D grid and right side indicates the desired output]k.imgur.com/BGPws.png

Comment: [`inpolygon`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inpolygon.html) may be helpful. Also, to get more help you should post a minimal example with code, and show what you have tried or where you got stuck

Comment: This is the sort of thing that is very well known within the field of computer graphics (drawing triangles on screen is the bread and butter there, and that is exactly the same problem as yours). I recommend you search for a solution using those terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
[X, Y] = meshgrid(1:1300, 1:1300);
Z = ones(size(X));

p = [500 0; 1000 0; 1000 500]'; % polygon points

indx = inpolygon(X(:), Y(:), p(1,:), p(2,:));

Z2 = Z;
Z2(indx) = 0;

figure('position', [200 200 1000 400])
subplot(1,2,1);
pcolor(X, Y, Z);  shading flat; colorbar; caxis([0, 2]); daspect([1,1,1]);
subplot(1,2,2);
pcolor(X, Y, Z2);  shading flat; colorbar; caxis([0, 2]);daspect([1,1,1]);
```

[image]